# Need advice on where to go with program

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am writing a program to allow a customer can place a sandwich order via a JFrame GUI (with Swing). I want the customer to be able to place multiple orders.

Currentyly, you would open the program and select what you want.  A window pops up showing your selection.  I want the user to be able to place another order if they choose (this is the part I haven't figured out yet). All the while, I want to be able to track their total so I can display a grand total after they finish ordering. My code works for simple placing a single order:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;


public class SubwayMobileOrder
{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Order placeOrder = new Order();

        placeOrder.placeOrder();

        placeOrder.printOrder();

    }
}

class TabletScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    // Customer name
    private JLabel jlbCustomerName = new JLabel("Enter a Name for the order:");
    private JTextField jtfCustomerName = new JTextField(15);

    // Bread choices
    private JLabel jlbBread = new JLabel("Choose a type of bread");
    private JComboBox jcbBreadType = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Select Bread Type", "Italin Herbs and Cheese", "Wheat"});

    // Sub Size
    private JLabel jlbSize = new JLabel("What size sub would you like");
    private JComboBox jcbSize = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Select Sub Size", "12 inch", "6 inch"});

    // Sub meat
    private JLabel jlbMeat = new JLabel("Select what Meat(s) you would like");
    private JCheckBox jcxChicken = new JCheckBox("Chicken");
    private JCheckBox jcxBacon = new JCheckBox("Bacon");

    // Sub Cheese
    private JLabel jlbCheese = new JLabel("Select what Cheese(s) you would like");
    private JCheckBox jcxAmerican = new JCheckBox("American");
    private JCheckBox jcxSwiss = new JCheckBox("Swiss");

    // Ingrediants ie veggies and what not
    private JLabel jlbVeggies = new JLabel("Select what Veggies you would like");
    private JCheckBox jcxOnion = new JCheckBox("Onion");
    private JCheckBox jcxLettuce = new JCheckBox("Lettuce");

    // Addons
    private JLabel jlbDoubleCheese = new JLabel("Double Cheese");
    private JComboBox jcbDoubleCheese = new JComboBox(new Object[] {"yes", "no"});


    private JLabel jlbDoubleMeat = new JLabel("Double Meat");
    private JComboBox jcbDoubleMeat = new JComboBox(new Object[] {"yes", "no"});

    // Ok button
    JButton okButton = new JButton("Sub Complete");


    public TabletScreen() {

        // Main panel with: name, bread type, size
        JPanel mainOrderInfo = new JPanel();
        mainOrderInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1, 10, 10));
        mainOrderInfo.add(jlbCustomerName);
        mainOrderInfo.add(jtfCustomerName);
        mainOrderInfo.add(jlbBread);
        mainOrderInfo.add(jcbBreadType);
        mainOrderInfo.add(jlbSize);
        mainOrderInfo.add(jcbSize);

        // Meat Panel
        JPanel meatPanel = new JPanel();
        meatPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
        meatPanel.add(jlbMeat);
        meatPanel.add(jcxBacon);
        meatPanel.add(jcxChicken);

        // Cheese Panel
        JPanel cheesePanel = new JPanel();
        cheesePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
        cheesePanel.add(jlbCheese);
        cheesePanel.add(jcxAmerican);
        cheesePanel.add(jcxSwiss);

        // Veggies Panel
        JPanel veggiesPanel = new JPanel();
        veggiesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
        veggiesPanel.add(jlbVeggies);
        veggiesPanel.add(jcxOnion);
        veggiesPanel.add(jcxLettuce);

        // Addons Panel
        JPanel addonsPanel = new JPanel();
        addonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 10, 10));
        addonsPanel.add(jlbDoubleCheese);
        addonsPanel.add(jcbDoubleCheese);
        addonsPanel.add(jlbDoubleMeat);
        addonsPanel.add(jcbDoubleMeat);

        // Setup overall main panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5, 15, 15));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        mainPanel.setOpaque(true);
        mainPanel.add(mainOrderInfo);
        mainPanel.add(meatPanel);
        mainPanel.add(cheesePanel);
        mainPanel.add(veggiesPanel);
        mainPanel.add(addonsPanel);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 10, 10));
        buttonPanel.add(okButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        okButton.addActionListener(this);

    }


        //------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();
            Order order = new Order();

            // getting bread
            if (jcbBreadType.getSelectedIndex() == 1)
             { sub.addSub(new ItlainHerbs()); }
            if (jcbBreadType.getSelectedIndex() == 2)
                { sub.addSub(new Wheat()); }

            // getting meat
            if (jcxBacon.isSelected())
                { sub.addSub(new Bacon()); }
            if (jcxChicken.isSelected())
                { sub.addSub(new Chicken()); }

            // getting cheese
            if (jcxAmerican.isSelected())
                { sub.addSub(new American()); }
            if (jcxSwiss.isSelected())
                { sub.addSub(new Swiss()); }

            // getting veggies
            if (jcxOnion.isSelected())
                { sub.addSub(new Onion()); }
            if (jcxLettuce.isSelected())
                { sub.addSub(new Lettuce()); }

            // getting

            order.addOrder(sub);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sub.toString());

        }



}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
class Order
{
    private static ArrayList<Sandwich> order = new ArrayList<Sandwich>(15);

    public Order() {}

    public void addOrder(Sandwich a)
    {
        order.add(a);
    }

    public void placeOrder()
    {
        JFrame frame = new TabletScreen();
        frame.setTitle("Subway Order App");
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void printOrder()
    {
        String totalOrder = "\nThis is your total order \n";
        for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++)
        {
            if (order.get(i) instanceof Sandwich)
            {
                totalOrder += "\nSub: " + order.get(i);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, totalOrder);
        }

    }
}

class Sandwich
{
    private ArrayList<Sub> sub = new ArrayList<Sub>(20);

    public Sandwich() {}

    public void addSub(Sub x) { sub.add(x); }


    public String toString()
    {
        String yourOrder = "\n Your Sub is as follows: \n ";
        for (int i = 0; i < sub.size(); i++)
        {
            if (sub.get(i) instanceof Bread)
                { yourOrder += "\nBread type: " + sub.get(i); }
            if (sub.get(i) instanceof Meat)
                { yourOrder += "\nMeat type: " + sub.get(i); }
            if (sub.get(i) instanceof Cheese)
                { yourOrder += "\nCheese type: " + sub.get(i); }
            if (sub.get(i) instanceof Veggies)
                { yourOrder += "\nVeggie type: " + sub.get(i); }

        }

        return yourOrder;
    }
}

//===============================================================\\

class Sub // Sub super class
{
    Sub() {}
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------\\
class Bread extends Sub
{
    String bread;
    Bread(String bread) { this.bread = bread; }

    public String toString() { return bread; }
}

class ItlainHerbs extends Bread
{
    ItlainHerbs() { super("Italin Herbs and Cheese"); }
}

class Wheat extends Bread
{
    Wheat() { super("Wheat"); }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------\\

class Meat extends Sub
{
    String meat;
    Meat(String meat) { this.meat = meat; }

    public String toString() { return meat; }
}

class Bacon extends Meat
{
    Bacon() { super("Bacon"); }
}

class Chicken extends Meat
{
    Chicken() { super("Chiken"); }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------\\
class Cheese extends Sub
{
    String cheese;
    Cheese(String cheese) { this.cheese = cheese; }

    public String toString() { return cheese; }
}

class American extends Cheese
{
    American() { super("American"); }
}

class Swiss extends Cheese
{
    Swiss() { super("Swiss"); }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------\\
class Veggies extends Sub
{
    String veggies;
    Veggies(String veggies) { this.veggies = veggies; }

    public String toString() { return veggies; }
}

class Onion extends Veggies
{
    Onion() { super("Onion"); }
}

class Lettuce extends Veggies
{
    Lettuce() { super("Lettuce"); }
}

//===============================================================\\
```

Comment: This is a too open-ended question much better suited for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SimonShine If the code is working as intended, it is a good advice. But, from what I can see, this is a request to change functionality to allow multiple requests at once, which is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: The subject says "need advice" and does not actually ask anything. This is ideal material for Code Review if the question is posed right, e.g.: "I want to make X. I've already made Y. What changes need to be made to X so that I can gracefully accomplish Y?"

Comment: "Here's code that works. I want someone to add more functionality to it." Yep, off topic for SO either way.

Comment: Im new to stack overflow and was not aware of the Coder Review section. I will definitely use that in the future for advice seeking like this. I finished the program and was able to work it out myself (took some time though). Either way I appreciate all of your time and will check out the coder review section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have an initial JFrame containing a JTable or JList (initially empty), an add and a delete button. the Add button would bring up your JFrame. Upon completion of the order, a new row would be added to the table/list. 
Selecting the row (or possibly more than one) would enable the delete button, otherwise normally disabled. Pressing the delete button would remove the selected entries.

Whether to use a list or table depends on whether you want to show just the order name, or all the fields.